# Grails Integration Test - Duplicate Form Submission always invalidToken

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I have tried in my Unit Test to test duplicate form submission like in the docs and it worked.
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers

But in my Integration Test, it was always failed and marked as invalidToken. I write it in the same way like unit test in tokenHolder's part.

So how to handle valid token withForm in Integration Test?

My Integration Test:

```
@TestFor(RegisterTestedController)
class RegisterTestedControllerIntSpec extends Specification {
    void "test insert data register"() {
        given:
        controller.params.username == 'babaenciel'
        controller.params.companyName == 'tamago'

        when:
        def tokenHolder = SynchronizerTokensHolder.store(session)
        params[SynchronizerTokensHolder.TOKEN_URI] = '/registerTested/signUp'
        params[SynchronizerTokensHolder.TOKEN_KEY] = tokenHolder.generateToken(params[SynchronizerTokensHolder.TOKEN_URI])

        controller.signUp()

        then:        
        controller.modelAndView.model.parameter.username == 'babaenciel'
        controller.modelAndView.model.parameter.companyName == 'tamago'
    }
}
```

The Controller:

```
class RegisterTestedController {
    def signUp() {
        log.info("session: " + session.properties)
        log.info("request: " + request.properties)
        log.info("params: " + params)

        def invalidToken = false

        withForm {
            invalidToken = false
        }.invalidToken {
            invalidToken = true
        }

        log.info("invalid token: " + invalidToken)

        if(invalidToken) {
            flash.code = 'alert-red'
            flash.message = message(code: "error.general.multipleSubmission")
            redirect action:'index'
            return
        }        

        render view: 'index', model: [parameter: params]
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In integration tests the params need to be set for a new controller instance that you have to create manually (See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting). Also the session is not available in the integration tests by default. You can get it via the `RequestContextHolder` like this: `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().session`.

The complete code should look like this:

```
YourController yourController = new YourController()

def token = SynchronizerTokensHolder.store(RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().session)
yourController.params[SynchronizerTokensHolder.TOKEN_URI] = '/yourController/yourAction'
yourController.params[SynchronizerTokensHolder.TOKEN_KEY] = token.generateToken(yourController.params[SynchronizerTokensHolder.TOKEN_URI])

yourController.yourAction()
```

Also note: In Grails 3.0 it is recommended to use functional tests instead of integration tests. See "Testing Controllers" in section [Integration Testing](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.0/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting) of the Grails Reference Documentation.